# What is the CSS code to put shadows in the letters?

Tags: html, css, shadow

The title says everything. What is the CSS code to put shadows in the letters?

Comment: Not HTML, CSS.  Updated question.

Comment: @Kon: Rolled back because your edit alters the meaning of the question completely. I think it's better to clarify with the OP what he's looking for first.

Comment: @BoltClock, he wants to put shadows on text.  That's the end goal.

Comment: @Kon: Yeah but is he looking for an HTML solution or a CSS solution? If the question is changed to say CSS our answers would have to be changed too because we addressed the HTML bit. And I think that's better for the OP to decide instead of anyone else...

Comment: Eh, whatever.  I don't care enough to continue the argument.  :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way to achieve this with HTML.

In supporting browsers, you can use the [text-shadow](http://www.css3.info/preview/text-shadow/) property from CSS.